# QGIS Server MAP request parameter

Tags: wms, qgis-server

How to setup parameter MAP for QGIS Server request, if my project in PostGIS database?
"Database path" of project has ampersand:

```
postgresql://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=mydb&schema=myschema&project=myproject
```

And if I send to URL, QGIS Server can't correctly parse it:

```
http://localhost:8000?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=postgresql://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=mydb&schema=myschema&project=myproject
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. All params can be send throw POST, with x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode your parameter.

Using https://www.urlencoder.org/, this :

`postgresql://localhost:5432?sslmode=disable&dbname=mydb&schema=myschema&project=myproject`

would give :

`postgresql%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5432%3Fsslmode%3Ddisable%26dbname%3Dmydb%26schema%3Dmyschema%26project%3Dmyproject`